# How to assigne a value to Action delegate in Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to assigne true to the `Action` parametre with moq

```
void SaveAllCustomers(
        List<Customer> Customers,
        Action<bool, string> result);
```

so I can verify the coverage based on the `result` of that operation. how can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback when setting up the mock

```
mock
    .Setup(_ => _.SaveAllCustomers(It.IsAny<List<Customer>>(), It.IsAny<Action<bool, string>>()))
    .Callback((List<Customer> customers, Action<bool, string> result) => {
        if(result != null)
            result(true, "");            
    });
```

Comment: I got this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Ok you need to provide more context. Show the test and how the mock is used. Update the original question with those details.

Comment: it is weird, the method under test is async, so when i remove task async and await from the 'act' part, it works